# How many meats can make a meatball?

Tags: meat, lamb, meatballs, veal, meatloaf

So I want make a Swedish meatball style meatloaf. When I make Swedish meatballs I usually use veal and ground pork, but I've always wanted to throw in some ground lamb and buffalo.

So the specific question here is for a meatball how many of these meats can I get away with including in these balls
Of juicy meat?

And more generally, what are the guiding principles in combing meats from
Different animals like this? Hoping there's like a periodic table of savory sensations I can put on the kitchen wall, but any anecdotal suggestions will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made meatballs from Beef, pork, beef/pork blend, chicken, all kinds of fish (from white fish to blue fish), self caught blue crab, even clams but those were more like fritters than meat balls to be honest, even out of chick peas (those are actually called falafel and not really a meat ball, but they are similar)

Season appropriately for the meats you are using, and make sure you use the right amount of egg and breading so that it stays together. Some really non-fatty meats you may be adding some oil to the meatball mash so they aren't all dried out.

I like to fry meat balls in a thin layer of oil, but I also like cooking them directly in sauce if I am making enough sauce to cover them all.

Comment: You are very close to a good answer. Quantify "enough" egg and breading per pound or kilo of meat, and consider fat content.

Comment: Well trading recipes isn't really in scope for this site

Comment: True, but without quantifying "enough", it's a half answer. I do it by feel as far as bread crumbs or such, 1 egg per pound of meat and aim for 10-15% fat. That isn't a recipe, but combined with your answer it kind of answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to combine as many as you want.  Pay attention to the fat content in each meat, as that can make a big difference in the yield as well as the texture.  However, even if you make a fairly significant change (for example, from 20% fat to 10% fat), it still won't be wrong or inedible, just different.  (Although, I wouldn't recommend trying anything insane like 95% fat.  It's no longer a meatball/meatloaf at that point.)

The meatballs I regularly make were derived from a Swedish meatball recipe.  I use 100% ground beef instead of the other meats, and it works really well.  Also, instead of the traditional Swedish meatball sauce, I use marinara sauce.  It's delicious!